# regex: smart regex for "ux/ui" string

Tags: regex

am a noob in regex and trying to generate the regex for the above string (which can also appear as "ui/ux" or "ui ux" or "ux ui") I came up with this so far

```
(u)(x|i)\/?\1\2
```

But this does not work. My question is how can i use backreferences for a capturing group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to stick with the back references, then you could use this:

[`(u)([xi])[\/ ]\1(?!\2)[xi]`](https://regex101.com/r/2XHDoy/1)

This says that the last character should be either `x` or `i` but not what was captured in the second group  (which also was `x` or `i`).

Note that back references are to what was matched, not to the pattern.

#### Alternative

Here is an alternative that aims to avoid repetition of `[xi]`, but it has some downsides:

- It will also match a separator that *follows* the pair
- The separator is optional, so it would also match `uxui`.
- It will not return separate captures for the first part of the pair, so you'll have to analyse the complete match to extract what you need afterwards.

[`(?:(u[xi])[\/ ]?(?!\1)){2}`](https://regex101.com/r/2XHDoy/2)

Comment: Thank you..perhaps am too naive but is there a way to remove the redundancy of [xi] repeating in the above expression?

Comment: No, but in the programming environment you use, you can of course deal with that by constructing the regular expression dynamically. Then the part `[xi]` would be in some string variable, which you would just repeat while building the regex.

Comment: Still, I added an alternative that avoids the repetition, but it has some disadvantages.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure capture groups will be an effective approach to this pattern. I think you'll end up with a far more readable (and accurate) expression simply by enumerating the two possible orderings of "ux" and "ui":

```
(ux[\/ ]ui|ui[\/ ]ux)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/b4qzjD/1) on regex101

Comment: thanks but just for fun sake, can we avoid the duplication of characters and create a really smart regex?

Comment: Well, right off the bat, you can factor out the initial `u` to get `u(x[\ ]ui|i[\ ]ux)` but you can see you've already lost a little readability. But I agree, this is a fun regex puzzle; I'll post an edit if I come up with anything "smarter" ;)

Comment: @BoCode What's a "really smart regex"? One that is amazing in its complexity or one that gets the job done in a fast an obvious manner? In terms of maintainability, portability and most probably speed, this is better than the answer by trincot.

Comment: @wilusdaman FYI Generally there is no need to escape forward slashes in regular expressions, that's only necessary in a regex literal. Many languages define regex in string literals, where the forward slash escaping is superfluous (but quote escaping becomes necessary, for the same reason).

Comment: @tomalak I wanted something which avoids duplication of characters, the entire regex must be small and serves as an inspiration to help me learn. trincot came real close.. i guess there could be even smaller version of the above expression.